# Does the product of standard deviations of two random variables give their covariance?

Tags: statistics

Does the product of standard deviations of two random variables always give the covariance of these random variables?

If not, when does it specifically hold?

Comment: Not true in general. Covariance of independent variables is $0$ but the product of their deviations is not.

Comment: Could you please tell me when it specifically holds? I have added this part to my question.

Answer (score 2):

Not true in general. Covariance of independent variables is $0$ but the product of their deviations is not.

The ratio of the covariance of random variables and the product of their standard deviations is called the correlation coefficient between the random variables. $$r_{XY}=\frac{\text{Cov}(X,Y)}{\sigma_X\sigma_Y}\in[-1,1]$$$r_{XY}=1$ [corresponds to a positive linear relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient#Mathematical_properties) between $X,Y$ i.e. $Y=aX+b,a>0$.